# Running a rails RJS template from a jquery get request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjs

I am using Rails and jquery with RJS templates to perform various AJAX requests.

For most of my Ajax stuff I attach a submit handler to the form in my application.js as follows:

```
$('#tagging_flickr_photos').submitWithAjax();
$('#tag_submit').click(function() {
    $('#flickr-photos-status').show();

});
```

This calls the form action which does some processing and then forwards to a RJS template as follows:

```
$("#flickr-photos-status").hide();
$("#flickr-photos").fadeIn();
$("#flickr-photos").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'flickr_photos_for_tagging_content')) %>");
```

This works a treat.

Now I am trying to do the same but just based on selecting a different value in a dropdown and not submitting a form.
Here's my javascript to attach the handler to the dropdown:

```
$('#film_film_name_id').change(function() {
    $.get('/admin_film/make_tags?film_name_id=' + $("#film_film_name_id").val() + '&film_speed_id=' + $("#film_film_speed_id").val());
});
```

My controller method does some processing then forwards to the RJS template (make_tags.js.erb):

```
$("#film_tags").val(<%=@tags%>)
```

However, the template doesn't appear to execute.
I can see entries in my logs that it's calling my method and rendering the template but no matter what I put in the template nothing seems to happen.
I've put a Javascript alert in there and it doesn't fire.

I assume the problem is to do with attaching my Javascript handler but I can't figure out what I am missing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to tell jQuery that you are expecting JavaScript and that it should be executed. Try the following and see if it works:

```
$('#film_film_name_id').change(function() {
  var url = '/admin_film/make_tags?film_name_id=' + $("#film_film_name_id").val() + '&film_speed_id=' + $("#film_film_speed_id").val()
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'script',
    url: url
  });
});
```

Please check the jQuery docs on [jQuery.ajax()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) if it doesn't work as I haven't tested the code.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been fighting with this for several hours now.

Answer (score 1):

HI,

I'm using an observer that calls directly through the prototype library  (not jquery)

```
        <td><div id="outconditionnals_container">
                <% if !@milestone.howto.conditionnals.nil? then %>
                        <%= collection_select(:OUTconditionnal, :id, @milestone.howto.conditionnals, :id, :name, {:prompt => true}, {"index" => @outconditionnalID.to_s}) %>
                        <%= observe_field("OUTconditionnal_"+@outconditionnalID.to_s+"_id",
                                :url => { :action => :AJAX_selection_change },
                                :with => "'id='+value+'&dir=out&type=conditionnal&milestoneID="+@milestone.id.to_s+"'",
                                :on => "changed")%>                         
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Then my rjs is rendered from my action to referesh some other form elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - the other answer worked for me but I'll read up on the observer stuff when I get a chance as it looks useful.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also go with the **$.get** you've been using.
Here's your example with a hairdo:

```
$('#film_film_name_id').change(function() {
    $.get(
      '/admin_film/make_tags', // or something like '<%= make_tags_admin_film_path %>'
      {
        film_name_id: $("#film_film_name_id").val(),
        film_speed_id: $("#film_film_speed_id").val()
      },
      null, // you may define an additional callback here, if that makes sense
      "script"
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery method [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) is a nice shorthand for doing what ujh recommended above.